# Python Write a loop that creates a new word list, using a string method to strip the words from the list

Tags: python

PROBLEM 4. Write a loop that creates a new word list, using a
    string method to strip the words from the list created in Problem 3
    of all leading and trailing punctuation. Hint: the string library,
    which is imported above, contains a constant named punctuation.
    Three lines of code.

Okay, I have done the code as follows:

```
import string
text = ("There once was a man in Idaho, he invented the potato.")
listWords = text.split() #problem3
for i in string.punctuation:
    listWords = text.replace(i,"") #problem4
```

This code works, but it only removes quotations. How do I remove other forms of punctuation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: You already have a for loop. Just combine your code with the linked duplicate and you should be fine. On a different note, your code does not work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, those quotations are not a part of this text. This is just how this string variable is defined. So you are only looking on `,` and `.` here. You can clearly see it by printing your text word by word:

```
for word in listWords:
    print word
```

To remove any punctuation signs:

```
''.join(x for x in text if x not in string.punctuation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a for loop.  The problem is that if you do x = y.replace(foo,bar) inside a loop, you overwrite x each time.  If you do text = text.replace(i,""), that will incrementally remove the punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to remove the punctuation from the sentence first, then to split the words up. For example:

```
import string
text = ("There once was a man in Idaho, he invented the potato.")
out = text.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
listWords = text.split()
```